# Re-number A list of values Based on their Grouping

Tags: sql, select, case

I have the following items stored in a table:

```
List # | Sublist # | Sublist Priority
List A | Sublist 1 | 1
List A | Sublist 2 | 3
List B | Sublist 3 | 4
List B | Sublist 4 | 2
...
List X | Sublist 1 | 75
List X | Sublist 2 | 83
```

I would like to create an additional column which would recalculate Sublist Priority based on which List the Sublist is in. I want the query to look at each individual list, find the MIN value of the priority, then assign that Sublist a new priority of "1". Then find next Sublist WITHIN that List, and Assign it a priority of "2" and so on until all of Sublists in that List are given a new Priority in Ascending Order

```
List # | Sublist # | Sublist Priority | New Sublist Priority 
List A | Sublist 1 | 1                | 1
List A | Sublist 2 | 3                | 2
List B | Sublist 3 | 4                | 1
List B | Sublist 4 | 2                | 2
....
List X | Sublist 1 | 75               | 1
List X | Sublist 2 | 83               | 2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I don't understand "List B"'s new priority.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by list order by sublist_priority) as new_sublist_priority
from t;
```

This doesn't work for list "B", but that doesn't seem to follow your explanation.